# Get distinct rows except one column value

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

**Data will be like:**

```
date_time        | amount| user|group
---------------------
5/15/2017 6:30 | 250| a | abc
5/15/2017 6:30 | 250| a | def
5/15/2017 5:30 | 50| a |abc
5/15/2017 5:30 | 50| a |def
5/15/2017 4:30 | 50| a |abc
5/15/2017 4:30 | 50| a |def
5/15/2017 5:20 | 50| b |abc
5/15/2017 5:20 | 50| b |def
5/15/2017 5:18 | 50| b |abc
5/15/2017 5:18 | 50| b |def
```

**Desired result:**

```
date_time| amount | user  | group
---------------------
5/15/2017 4:30 | 50| a |abc
5/15/2017 4:30 | 50| a |def
5/15/2017 6:30 | 250| a | abc
5/15/2017 6:30 | 250| a | def
5/15/2017 5:18 | 50| b |abc
5/15/2017 5:18 | 50| b |def
```

Result with distinct values without considering date-time column and for entire group, the distinct should not apply on datetime.

Comment: This question is not clear, we need more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;With cte(date_time, amount,[user],[group])
AS
(
SELECT '5/15/2017 6:30' , 250, 'a' , 'abc' Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 6:30' , 250, 'a' ,'def'  Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 5:30' , 50, 'a' ,'abc'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 5:30' , 50, 'a' ,'def'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 4:30' , 50, 'a' ,'abc'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 4:30' , 50, 'a' ,'def'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 5:20' , 50, 'b' ,'abc'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 5:20' , 50, 'b' ,'def'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 5:18' , 50, 'b' ,'abc'   Union all
SELECT '5/15/2017 5:18' , 50, 'b' ,'def'
)

SELECT date_time
    ,amount
    ,[user]
    ,[group]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY amount
            ,[user]
            ,[group] ORDER BY amount
                ,[user]
            ) seq
    FROM cte
    ) dt
WHERE dt.seq = 1
ORDER BY [user]
```

Below is output :

```
date_time   amount  user    group
--------------------------------
5/15/2017   4:30    50  a   abc
5/15/2017   5:30    50  a   def
5/15/2017   6:30    250 a   abc
5/15/2017   6:30    250 a   def
5/15/2017   5:18    50  b   abc
5/15/2017   5:18    50  b   def
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number and partition by amount, user, group as below:

```
select top 1 with ties * from YourdateTable
    order by row_number() over (partition by amount, [user], [group] order by amount, [user], [group])
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+--------+------+-------+
|        date_time        | amount | user | group |
+-------------------------+--------+------+-------+
| 2017-05-15 05:30:00.000 |     50 | a    | abc   |
| 2017-05-15 04:30:00.000 |     50 | a    | def   |
| 2017-05-15 05:20:00.000 |     50 | b    | abc   |
| 2017-05-15 05:18:00.000 |     50 | b    | def   |
| 2017-05-15 06:30:00.000 |    250 | a    | abc   |
| 2017-05-15 06:30:00.000 |    250 | a    | def   |
+-------------------------+--------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(date_time) AS date_time, amount, [user], [group]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [user], amount, [group];
```

From your above data it does not matter which date you select so **MIN()** was used to select date which is not in the *GROUP BY* i.e. not distinct.